# How to get the Message read/unread report in xmpp frame work?

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

HI I am developing chat app so i am using xmpp framework.Chatting is working fine but how to get the message delivery like in whatsapp, facebook etc.,i searched for that i found some document here is my code upto now i am implemented

in connect Method

```
XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
[xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:self.xmppStream];
```

added this lines in sending messsage method

```
NSXMLElement *request = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"request"];
 [request addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];
 [message addChild:request];
[message addChild:body];
```

but This is for message delivered or not how can we check the deliverd message read or not i have seen these extentions XEP-0184,XEP-0333 but I don't have any idea to implement the read /unread messages. please help me

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the read receipts then instead of sending auto message delivery receipts, send it whenever user reads that message. Each message has it's corresponding message_id. Use that message_id to send the delivery receipt for the particular message that has been read. So, comment the following line

```
//xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
```

I solved this problem by adding 'chatStatus' attribute in my message entity. For sender I have kept value of chatStatus as sent, unsent, or received(received by other side or not). For Receiver Side I have kept the Values as read or unread(Have I read message or not, So that for unread message I could send read Receipts).

On Click Of send Button:

```
//Save to your Message Entity 

NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject: message_body forKey:@"message_body"];
[m setObject:messageID forKey:@"message_id"];
[m setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"isOutgoing"];
[m setObject:dateString forKey:@"date"];
[m setObject:timeString forKey:@"time"];
[m setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
[m setObject:yourId forKey:@"from"];
[m setObject:toId forKey:@"to"];

if (!Is_InternetAvailable]) {
 [m setObject:unsent forKey:@"chatStatus"];
}
else{
 [m setObject:sent forKey:@"chatStatus"];
}
[[CoreDataMethods sharedCoreDataMethods] saveUserMessage:m];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if ([message isoutGoing]) {//If I have sent the message

        // Mine bubble
        if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:unsent]) {
            //set unsent image
        }
        else if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:sent]){
            //set sent image
        }
        else if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:received]){
          //set Received Image
        }
    }
    else{
        // Other Bubble , Notify them that you have read the message if it is unread/new message

        if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:unread]) {

            //send read receipt
                NSXMLElement *receivedelement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"received" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];

                NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message" xmlns:@"jabber:client"];
                [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:toId];
                [message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:fromID];
                [receivedelement addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:[messageDict valueForKey:@"message_id"]];
                [message addChild:receivedelement];

                //XMPPMessage *generatedReceiptResponse = [[messageDict valueForKey:@"xmppMessage"] generateReceiptResponse];
                [[[kAppDelegate xmppHandler] xmppStream] sendElement:message];

                // update message entity
                [self updateChatStatus:read withMessageID:[messageDict valueForKey:@"message_id"]];
        }
    }
```

And finally when you receive the delivery Receipt in didReceiveMessage, update the chatStatus to received

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{

if ([message hasReceiptResponse]) {//message read
//Update database message entity
 [self updateChatStatus:@"received" withMessageID:[message receiptResponseID]];
}
}
```

You could set the values of chatStatus as per your requirement. As for unsent messages I have set it as sent in didSendMessage delegate.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Thanks for replay can please tell me at sender side what have you done? are you storing every message in coredata with check status right? and how you know that particular message is read/sent/delivered?

Comment: If you are sending the message then you are sender and will set the ChatStatus to sent,unsent or received(chatStatus will be changed to received once you get the read receipt from other user in didReceiveMessage delegate). Yes I am storing every message in core data with chatStatus and updating it accordingly.  [[CoreDataMethods sharedCoreDataMethods] saveUserMessage:m] is used to save data in my message entity. I have made a singleton class for saving data into core data, you could replace this line with code to save data in core data.

Comment: but i am not saving my messages in core data i am using sqlite is it work or i need to maintain core data

Comment: Don't get confused between sender and receiver side. If you are sender of that message then keep the chatStatus value as sent, unsent or received. If you are receiving that message then put the value as read or unread(read if you have read the message, unread if you have not read the message because you were on other screen). for your unread messages send the readReceipt to sender of message and change ChatStatus to read. ChatStatus is attribute/field in 'message' table.

Comment: Using core data is a good approach. But sqlite will also work.  you have to just add one attribute chatStatus in your table whether it is core data or sqlite.

Comment: sure but one more thing are you able to check that delivered or read i am able to check that delivered using xep-0184 but based on your code how you implementaed that delivered with out using autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts

Comment: Please up vote my Question, it helpful to somebody else

Comment: Instead of using autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts I am sending the delivery receipts when user reads the message and have already mentioned code for that in my answer. I am using delivery receipts to check whether the user has read the message or not.

Comment: and what about the delivered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103719/discussion-between-swati-gupta-and-bittoo).

Comment: In my app I had to just show the read, sent and unset status, not the delivered status. If you also wanna show delivery status, then don't comment autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts and whenever messages are read send the IQ stanza to sender instead of delivery receipt.

Comment: If you want show delivery receipts also, then take one more value 'delivered ' for chatStatus on sender side.

Comment: HI Swathi can you please tell me how you assigned image in chat cell in my case my image are changing while scrolling and sending messages  can you please help me

Comment: @Bittoo the above condition only works with MESSAGE READ not with MESSAGE DELIVERED as reciever end user in on chat screen... how are you handling for MESSAGE DELIVERED

Comment: @SwatiGupta If i am a sender and sending a message then i found that the message is sent, and with the use of "hasReceiptResponse" Method i found that message is delivered. Now, My Question is how can i find this message is read or not ? if i use "hasReceiptResponse = true " (Method) for read, then how can I find message is deliver?