# How to get message delivered , seen , failed and unread message count in XMPP iOS? (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

i am developing chat app in that i have stuck in two scenario.

1) How to get message status like delivered ,seen etc.. 
   I have done following things :

```
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts!.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = true
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts!.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = true
```

but i do't get further idea, how can i further process to check message status ?

2) How to get un-read message count like whatsapp done?
   For get last recent message i have used below core data object `XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject`

Other Archive Code

```
self.xmppMessageArchivingStorage = XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
self.xmppMessageArchiving = XMPPMessageArchiving(messageArchivingStorage: xmppMessageArchivingStorage);
self.xmppMessageArchiving!.clientSideMessageArchivingOnly = true;
```

but let me know how can i get ur-read message count or help full snippet of code ?

I have alread checked below stack links :

1)[How to get the message delivery status using XMPP framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852336/how-to-get-the-message-delivary-status-using-xmpp-framework)

2)[Need assistance regarding using the xep-0184](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590975/need-assistance-regarding-using-the-xep-0184)

3)[How to get the message read/unread/report in xmpp framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244647/how-to-get-the-message-read-unread-report-in-xmpp-frame-work/35253579)

Server : [ejabber](https://www.ejabberd.im/)

Answer (score 3):

XMPP provides '**Stream Management'** to know whether message is delivered to XMPP server or not.

For that you have to register and activate it.
Here is the code.

```
// Stream Management 
func configureStreamManagement() {
  let xmppSMMS = XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage()
  xmppStreamManagement = XMPPStreamManagement(storage: xmppSMMS, dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
  xmppStreamManagement.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
  xmppStreamManagement.activate(xmppStream)
  xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = true
  xmppStreamManagement.ackResponseDelay = 0.2
  xmppStreamManagement.requestAck()
  xmppStreamManagement.automaticallyRequestAcks(afterStanzaCount: 1, orTimeout: 10)
  xmppStreamManagement.automaticallySendAcks(afterStanzaCount: 1, orTimeout: 10)
  xmppStreamManagement.enable(withResumption: true, maxTimeout: 0)
  xmppStreamManagement.sendAck()
  xmppStream.register(xmppStreamManagement)
}
```

Call this method after authentication is successful.

```
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
  print("Stream: Authenticated")
  configureStreamManagement()
}
```

Using the '**XMPPStreamManagementDelegate**' you can get the message ids which are delivered to XMPP server.

```
func xmppStreamManagement(_ sender: XMPPStreamManagement!, didReceiveAckForStanzaIds stanzaIds: [Any]!) {
  if let messageIds = stanzaIds as? [String] {
    for id in messageIds {
      print("Message is delivered to xmpp server: \(id)")
      // TODO: Custom code goes here to change the message status
    }
  }
}
```

As you have mentioned above, below code will automatically send delivered receipts of client, which means message is delivered to client.

```
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts!.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = true
self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts!.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = true
```

In '**XMPPStreamDelegate**' when message will be delivered to client you will get the receipt message.

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!) {
  print("Message From: \(message.from().user)")
  print("Message Body: \(message.body())")
  print("Message is delivered to client -: \(message.receiptResponseID())")
  // TODO: Compare receiptResponseID with sent message's id. 
}
```

Comment: If i am a sender and sending a message then i found that the message is sent, and with the use of "hasReceiptResponse" Method i found that message is delivered. Now, My Question is how can i find this message is read or not ? if i use "hasReceiptResponse = true " (Method) for read, then how can I find message is deliver?

Comment: @PriteshRaiyani, You can send XMLElement that chat between these two user is in active state. If chat is active, which means if user is in Message View and seeing the messages, all the messages status must be read.

Comment: I understood your point that when i am in messes screen then my all messages are read but how sender came to know that the message is deliver or seen? Actually, I am bit confused about deliver and read message. So, can you explain me XMLElement or didReceive for message how can identified Message delivered to client and read by client.

Comment: I have sent a message but not sent to XMPP server = COMPOSED .  Message Sent to XMPP server = SENT. Message sent to end user = DELIVERED. Message read by user = READ.