# How chat sent, read, Received work when other user not online / Offline at same time?

Tags: swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I already implemented XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts and working fine when both user online. My problem is other user send repose and User1 is offline.

Note - 
- I have only MUC chat feature. Not one to one chat. 
- I did code with help of 
link - ([How to get message delivered , seen , failed and unread message count in XMPP iOS? (Swift 3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570136/how-to-get-message-delivered-seen-failed-and-unread-message-count-in-xmpp-io?rq=1))

Case : 
 
User 1 : Hi (Online) ...(User2 Not online), 
After some time when user2 come online Fetch history. And receive message in willReceive method of stream. 
User 2 : Received HI (Sent receive receipt to MUC) (User1 not online) 
User1 :
After some time when user1 come online fetch history.

Now In this method(willReceive) I am not getting message with tag hasReceiptResponse which sent by user2.

- I want to know is this of getting history for latest method is wrong way ?
- If it is correct way then how I will get to know that user 2 have read/Received message ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not done with history. Read and delivery notifications are generated by clients not by server.